# Unable to read the resource file after deploying to Kubernetes

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, drone.io

I am running local code in traditional tomcat server where as while deploying to Kubernetes my code of read resource file is not working.

I placed `nas.txt` in resource folder.

and

```
File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:nas.txt");

//Read File Content
String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));
return content;
```

This is giving `"Internal exception has occurred"` error

Answer (score 1):

Is the file present in tomcat - - >webapps  -->app°war--> resources inside the container

Answer (score 0):

`ResourceUtils.getFile` doesn't work with packaged jars. Though it works with IDEs. You can try below alternate

```
protected InputStreamReader readStream(String filePath) throws FileNotFoundException {
    InputStreamReader streamReader;
    if (filePath.startsWith("classpath:")) {
        streamReader = new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream(File.separator + filePath.split("classpath:/*")[1]));
    } else {
        streamReader = new FileReader(ResourceUtils.getFile(filePath));
    }
    return streamReader;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your file in `resources` directory

```
URL img1Url = org.apache.cxf.common.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.getResource("/assets/bathroom.png", YourClass.class);
```

Use the url to create a `File` Object or an `InputStreamReader` as per your application.

Library import:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-common-utilities</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.11</version>
</dependency>
```

The above part works for kubernetes images and regular instances as well.